# How to create a Swift filter query based on multiple conditions?

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

I am currently recording the discovery preference of a `User` (see image below) and would like to filter the list of `Users` being displayed in a `CollectionView` that meet the discovery preferences set by the `User`.

[image]

Every `User` in the array has a `birthYear`, `gender` and `discoverable` `Bool`.

This is my function which currently works for only the  `discoverable` Bool and displays only User's which are set to `true`.

**How do I chain the filter conditions that I need in order to only display those Users that meet the discovery preferences of a User above?**

```
    func discoverUsers(location: CLLocation) {

        DataService.run.getUsersAtVenue(forVenueLocation: location, forUid: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (users, success) in

            if success {
                self.users = users

                self.filteredUsers = self.users.filter({ (user: User) -> Bool in
                    return user.discoverable == true

                    //-> Chain filter conditions to check for here: gender, age
                })

                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 0.5)

            }//end if

        }//end closure

    }//end func


}//end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding precisely what you want to achieve in particular. However, here is how the filter function plays out:

Given that users is an array of elements of type:

```
struct User {
    let age: Int
    let isMale: Bool
    // ...
}
```

You can filter like so:

```
filteredUsers = users.filter { user in
     return (user.age <= maxAge && user.age >= minAge) && /* include any other condition you need */ 
}
```

Comment: yeah this actually helped...I'm still a beginner and didn't realise that you can simply bind the filter condition one after another in the way you have shown.

Comment: Alright I am really glad it helped! Try to do more research by your own as you gain expertise as a "How to use the filter function in swift" Google search or a quick look at apple's book on swift would be enough to answer your question for example